# Nawk Commmad in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, awk, nawk

I have a nawk command as shown.
Can anyone explain what this command is suppose to do.

```
set sampFile = $cur_dir/${qtr}.SAMP

nawk -F "," '{OFS=","; if (($4 == "0000" || $4 == "00000000")) {print $0} }' $samp_input_file >! $sampFile
```

Comment: I've never seen `>!` redirection -- is that supposed to be `>|` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file pointed to by the variable `$samp_input_file` this command will print the lines where the 4th field is either `0000` or `00000000` and store the output in the file pointed to by `$sampFile`.

```
1,2,3,00
2,2,3,0000
3,2,3,000
4,2,3,00000000
5,2,3,0000

# Cleaner version 
awk '{FS=OFS=","; if ($4 == "0000" || $4 == "00000000") print}' file
2,2,3,0000
4,2,3,00000000
5,2,3,0000
```

Comment: So which ever line contains 0000 or 00000000 those lines will be added in the sampFile one line after the other right?

Comment: Note quite, **only** if the 4th value/column/record has exactly 4 or 8 zeros will the line be added to to `$sampFile`.

Comment: Cleaner yet: `awk -F, '$4 ~ /^0000(0000)?$/' file` and if you use an awk that supports RE intervals: `awk -F, '$4 ~ /^(0000){1,2}$/' file`.

Comment: Yeah didn't think it was appropriate here to go to clever, keep the awk tips coming